# Popup opened by me being closed after redirect

Tags: javascript, authentication, popup

I'm opening a popup to an external website where my users can login and get redirected to my website with a code (?code=xxxx) on the url. When they return I save that code so I can then use it on the main site.

I can open the window fine, the user can login to the other service and it get's redirected to my page but when they get redirected the popup is closed before I get the chance to save the code.

I tried disabling the default link behaviour but that doesn't solve issue. If the page opened isn't redirect the popup never closes.

**page.js**

```
function login(event) {
   window.open(link,'Auth','height=675,width=750');
   event.preventDefault();
}

loginButton.addEventListener('click', login);
```

**popup.js (this code doesn't run)**

```
var params = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
if (params.has('code')) {
    var code = params.get('code');
    Cookies.set('code', code);
}
```

The button is a simple  element (already tried with no href):

```
<a href="https://test.test.test.com/" id="test-login-button" class="button test">
  <span class="icon">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/icons/test.png') }}" alt="Test" />
  </span>
<span>Login</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML you are using?

Comment: @Ben Added to the post, just replaced some identifying info and replaced with test.

Comment: Where is the button in the HTML code?

Comment: @Ben It's the a element, it's not really a button element. I get it like this:
var loginButton = document.getElementById('test-login-button');